# Input não recebe valor ao clicar no Button

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldade em utilizar o `getElementById`.

Quando executo meu código e clico no botão, aparentemente o valor inserido no `input` não é recebido.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
var teste1 = document.getElementById("teste").value;

var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.onclick = document.write(teste1);
```

```html
<input id="teste"/>
<button>Testar</button>
```

Comment: O `onclick` deveria chamar uma função.

Comment: Como assim o valor não é recebido? Quem deveria receber esse valor? Seu problema é o `getElementById`?

Answer (score 4):

Seu problema é que precisa ler o valor do campo ao clicar no botão e não antes, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.onclick = function(e){
   // deve ler o valor ao clicar e nao antes
    var teste1 = document.getElementById("teste").value;
    document.write(teste1);
}
```

```html
<input id="teste"/>
<button>Testar</button>
```

Comment: Uma dúvida: Eu tenho atribuir a função inteira ao button.onclick ou posso escrever a função e depois fazer button.onclick = function();? ou então document.write("O valor do teste é: "+function());

Comment: Pode sim. Se sua *function* não tiver parametros, pode ser bem simples assim: `button.onclick = nomedasuafunction`

Comment: Pode fazer assim também: `button.onclick = function(e){ nomedasuafunction(e); }`

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo usando o evento de click no botão:

HTML:

```
<input id="teste"/>
<button>Testar</button>
<span id="result"></span>
```

JS:

```
var teste1 = document.getElementById("teste");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  result.innerText = teste1.value;
//   document.write(teste1.value);
})
```